# vb 2010 - issue getting focused index of selected row in listview

Tags: vb.net

i have setup a listview with the following properties:

```
FullRowSelect = True
GridLines = True
View = Details
HeaderStyle = Nonclickable
Multiselect = False
```

i have created 4 columns, and populated them with 10 rows of data. i want to get the row number every time i click on a row in the listview. i have done this as follows:

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged

indexNo = ListView1.FocusedItem.Index
label1.text = indexNo.ToString

End Sub
```

indexNo is a publicly declared string.

when i click on a different row in the listview, i get the following error:

```
NullReferenceException was unhandled
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure something is selected first:

```
    If Not IsNothing(ListView1.FocusedItem) Then
        indexNo = ListView1.FocusedItem.Index
        Label1.Text = indexNo.ToString
    End If
```

Alternatively, check the length of the [SelectedIndices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices(v=vs.110).aspx) collection:

```
    If ListView1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0 Then
        indexNo = ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)
        Label1.Text = indexNo.ToString
    End If
```